# Trying and failing to test promises with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise

*(all this example code is coffeescript)*

I have a generic promise like so:

```
describe "foo", () ->
  it "foo", () ->

    p = new Promise (r) -> r(1)
    p.then (x) ->
      console.log("promise run")
      expect(x).toEqual(2)
```

This is expected to fail, but it doesn't. The expectation is never hit and nothing is logged either.

From [the jasmine team's blog post on the topic](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/testing-javascript-promises) it seems I can write something like this:

```
p.then (x) ->
  expect(x).toEqual(2)
  done()
```

but it has the same effect.

The blog post recommends the [mock-promises](https://github.com/charleshansen/mock-promises) library, which I used to write this:

```
p.then (x) ->
  console.log x
  expect(x).toEqual(2)
MockPromises.executeForPromise(p);
```

but it has the same effect (the expectation is never hit)

Comment: If your test runner still doesn't accept promises as return values in 2016, it might be time to change it (or just update?)

Comment: Protip: `p = Promise.resolve 1`

Comment: @bergi, did you see i already posted an answer for myself? It is possible i was just missing something very minor. Anyway do you have a suggestion for a better testing library than Jasmine?

Comment: I believe your answer only times out instead of logging the exception, right? I'm not an expert on the market, but I know that your first snippet works in Mocha.

Comment: It was not timing out. Just skipping the then call entirely and saying it passed. Thanks for the recommendation to try mocha though

Comment: I meant in the answer below you're getting a timeout, don't you? As `done()` is never called after the failed expectation.

Comment: @Bergi actually yeah, how would I fix this?

Comment: You could add a `.catch(done)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant gratification:

it's an easy fix:

all I needed to do was pass `done` as an argument to the `it` function:

```
describe "foo", () ->
  it "foo", (done) ->
    p = new Promise (r) -> r(1)
    p.then (x) ->
      console.log x
      expect(x).toEqual(2)
      done()
```

Thanks to a suggestion in the comments I should also add

```
.catch(done)
```

at the end so that failed cases don't just time out.